# Minus sign in SVG rendered as "K"

Tags: svg

When generating a basic plot in Maple 2022:

```
Expr := x;
with(plots):
inequal(Expr < y, x = -3 .. 3, y = -3 .. 3);
```

I get the expected output:

[image]

But when exporting the plot as an .svg file and adding it to a Latex document, the minus sign is now rendered as "K":
[image]

What  is causing this and how to fix it? The svg looks fine in Chrome/Edge.
MWE in Overleaf:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{svg, graphicx, float}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includesvg{test.svg}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Edit: [test.svg](https://pastebin.com/raw/JPFD9NqF)

Opening the file in Edge/inkscpae:

[image]

[image]

Comment: please add `test.svg`  to your question, otherwise we can not use your example

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `test.svg` added

Comment: if I view that svg it shows as K and K is in the source `<text x="7" xml:space="preserve" y="271"
                  style="clip-path:url(#clipPath6); stroke:none;">K</text>` so including in to latex will not change this

Comment: Seems to be more a problem with the Maple export than a tex problem. Maybe better suited on a Q&A site for maple?

Comment: What do you mean by "The svg looks fine in Chrome/Edge"? As @DavidCarlisle writes, the svg contains a "K", so why would Chrome/Edge not show a `K`? -and of cause also LaTeX. On my system, Safari, Chrome, Inkscape and mac preview shows `K` - that is because it is a K.

Comment: @hpekristiansen that's weird, i don't see `k` when i open it in Edge/Chrome/Inkscape. See the 2 screenshots i added

Comment: As with @hpekristiansen I see a K in Firefox/Chrome/Inkscape on linux.

Comment: @ZA_: Could you try to download this file: https://pastebin.com/raw/JPFD9NqF , rename it to temp.svg and open it in inkscape?

Comment: A simple solution would be to take the `test.svg` that you uploaded to pastebin (which has the `K` in the source) and replace all occurrences of `K` with `-`. Of course you would need to do that again if the file changes, but in case the figure is already finished then this would be a quick workaround.

Comment: The OP doesn't see a `K` in browser because the font is installed (ESSTIXFive). This is presumably a non-Unicode font that Maple uses for symbols. The `svg` package uses *Inkscape* for conversion and that isn't doing anything clever with fonts. the `K` just gets passed through to LaTeX. I doubt there is much worth doing to fix this workflow other than using `sed 's/K/\$-\$/' < test.svg`.

Comment: @DavidPurton this indeed seems to be a font issue. A workaround i found is using .eps instead, which does display a `-` sign correctly.